# How to access files stored in Virtual Machine from Host

Tags: xcode, macos, windows-10, virtual-machine

I have a Mac OS X (10.11) virtual machine. But it has stopped working. It just about finishes loading the virtual machine and then just freezes on a black screen. Anyway, I wanna know if there is a way for me to recover the files on that virtual machine (Specifically Xcode files). They were not part of the shared folders so I'm not sure how to access them from the host (which is a windows 10).

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to do the following:

1. Create another virtual machine with Ubuntu
2. Attached the virtual disk image (.vdi) or whichever format you chose to store the OSX image as a second HDD to the Ubuntu VM.
3. Follow [these](https://askubuntu.com/questions/332315/how-to-read-and-write-hfs-journaled-external-hdd-in-ubuntu-without-access-to-os) instructions to enable HFS+ read write in the Ubuntu virual image.

Another way to do it would be to use something like [Arsenal Image mounter](https://arsenalrecon.com/apps/image-mounter/#use) which supports direct mounting of a bunch of virtual image formats including VDI, VHD etc.